# Android Studio build gradle as not found

Tags: android

i have the  problem in android studio 
Error:Could not read build file 'C:\Users\spotlight\AndroidStudioProjects\programmierpraktikumwise2014\gr2-android\Client\AOT-Messenger\app\build.gradle' as it does not exist. 
what should i do ? 
thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new project and copy the build.gradle (that the new project generate) file to your proyect in the same route.
The file should be in the root folder of the proyect.

For more info you can follow the official documentation of Android Studio.

http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio-build.html

Best regards.

Comment: thank you but i have yet a new problem Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 15 cannot be smaller than version L declared in library com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0-rc1 what should i do ?

Comment: This is becaouse your versions of the Manifest are incorrect. I think you have declared in min, max or target SDK version 'L'. With this version you need min, max and target as 'L', if you want an older version setup as (for example) min: 11, max: 20, target: 20.

But 'L' version requires all as 'L'.

Do this changes in the build.gradle